# El metodo sobreescrito paintComponent no me permite definir el color de fondo del JPanel o lamina

Tags: java, java-swing, paint

El metodo paintComponent no deja que se pinte de negro el JPanel, pero cuando comento el metodo si funciona ¿Por que pasa esto?

```
class LaminaConColor extends JPanel {

    public LaminaConColor() {

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponents(g);

        Color grisColor = new Color(100, 100, 100);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; // Grapichs2D herede de Graphics "Wooooh"

        Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 200, 150);
        g2.draw(rectangle2d);
        g2.setPaint(grisColor);// Lo mismo que setColor
        g2.fill(rectangle2d);

        Ellipse2D circulo2D = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        g2.setColor(new Color(100, 100, 100).brighter().brighter().brighter().darker());
        circulo2D.setFrame(rectangle2d);
        g2.fill(circulo2D);
        g2.draw(circulo2D);
    }

}

class LaminaConColor extends JPanel {

    public LaminaConColor() {

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

}
```

Comment: Por que al sobreescribir el paintComponent ya no tiene efecto la/s instrucción que hayas escrito en el constructor. Debes poner el `setBackground(Color.BLACK)` dentro del paintComponent

Comment: Lo probe así, no funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Noté que al sobrescribir el metodo, la instruccion setBackground funciona en el constructor del JFrame (Los JFrame no se les puede cambiar el color, solo se les puede agregar un JPanel con un color distinto encima ) es como si el JPanel y el JFrame ahora fueran el mismo objeto.

Bueno la solución: simplemente poner la instruccion setBackground en el constructor del JFrame.

class MarcoConColor extends JFrame {

```
int width = 500;
int height = 400;

public MarcoConColor() {

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(width, height);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Titulo cualquiera ");

    // Funciona solo si el metodo SI esta sobrescrito
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    Dibujitos lamina = new Dibujitos();
    add(lamina);

    // Funciona solo si el metodo NO esta sobrescrito
    // lamina.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

}
```

}

class Dibujitos extends JPanel {

```
public Dibujitos() {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

// El metodo
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponents(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 200, 150);
    g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
    g2.draw(rectangle2d);

    g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fill(rectangle2d);

    Ellipse2D circulo2D = new Ellipse2D.Double();
    g2.setColor(new Color(100, 100, 100).brighter().brighter().brighter().darker());
    circulo2D.setFrame(rectangle2d);
    g2.fill(circulo2D);
    g2.draw(circulo2D);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

La instrucción **setBackground(Color.black)** debe ir en el constructor del **JFrame**:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MarcoConColor extends JFrame{

    public MarcoConColor() {

        setBackground(Color.black);//acá o en cualquier otra parte de este constructor
        setTitle("Marco con digujos");
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new LaminaConColor());
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MarcoConColor();
    }

    class LaminaConColor extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponents(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; // Grapichs2D herede de Graphics "Wooooh"
            Color grisColor = new Color(100, 100, 100);
            Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 200, 150);
//            g2.draw(rectangle2d);  no hace falta, reemplazado por el método fill
            g2.setPaint(grisColor);// Lo mismo que setColor
            g2.fill(rectangle2d);

            Ellipse2D circulo2D = new Ellipse2D.Double();
            g2.setColor(new Color(100, 100, 100).brighter().brighter().brighter().darker());
            circulo2D.setFrame(rectangle2d);
            g2.fill(circulo2D);
//            g2.draw(circulo2D);  no hace falta, reemplazado por el método fill
        }
    }
}
```